# MVC - TextAreaFor does not display box

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have multiple projects in which this happens. I specify an TextBoxFor and I don't get a display of the text area box (i.e. no borders). I just get space of a row that looks like it is for the TextArea and if I hit return I get another. But no borders. This can't be the default. This happens for text boxes as well. Can anyone tell me why?

I have a ViewModel:

```
// Text Area - Whole Markup
        [Display(Name = "HTML Markup Code: ")]
        public string HTMLMarkupCode { get; set; }
```

And the markup:

```
<div class="col-xs-9">
                @Html.LabelFor(m =>  m.HTMLMarkupCode)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.HTMLMarkupCode)
            </div>
```

Comment: Is the a textarea in the generated html ? If yes it is a css problem

Comment: yes it is:  <label for="HTMLMarkupCode">HTML Markup Code: </label>
                <textarea cols="20" id="HTMLMarkupCode" name="HTMLMarkupCode" rows="2">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a CSS issue. Using the Chrome developer tools (F12) you can inspect the element and you can look at the computed CSS for the element. Then you should see that the border is probably set to 0 or none. You can then look under the Styles tab to figure out which CSS file and which line of the CSS has removed the borders.

Have a look: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

This is the quickest way to definitely find out what the issue is, otherwise you could go with a long trial and error approach, but you've got the tools to avoid it :)